# Does convergence of iterates imply convergence of function values?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

The question came to my find when I was reading convergence of gradient descent. However, my question is general and does not necessarily stick to GD. Concretely,my question is:
\begin{equation}
\|x^k-x^*\|_2 \rightarrow 0 \implies f(x^k)-f(x^*) \rightarrow 0 \quad  \text{and vice versa}?
\end{equation}
Assume whatever is necessary like convexity, lipschitz etc for iterative algorithms.
An example/counter example would  be great.

Comment: Why do you have a norm around $f(x^k)-f(x^*)$, which is presumably a scalar?

Comment: Removed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, the implication $\|x^k-x^*\|_2 \rightarrow 0 \implies f(x^k)-f(x^*) \rightarrow 0$ holds; this is known as a sequential characterization of continuous functions.

To prove the converse, additional hypotheses on $f$ are needed. Suppose $f$ is strictly convex and $x^*$ is the point of its minimum. Then it is true that $f(x^k)-f(x^*) \rightarrow 0 \implies \|x^k-x^*\|_2 \rightarrow 0 $. To prove this, consider the quantity
$$
m(r) = \min_{\|x-x^*\|=r} (f(x)-f(x^*)),\quad r>0
$$
Since $f$ is strictly convex, its point of minimum is unique; therefore $m(r)>0$ for any $r>0$. Convexity also implies that $f(x)-f(x^*)\ge m(r)$ when $\|x-x^*\|\ge r$. Rephrase this as: 
$$f(x)-f(x^*)< m(r) \implies  \|x-x^*\| <r$$
and you have the conclusion.